# I have to click my window before interacting with my game

Tags: java

I have a simple game and when I run the program I have to click on the window before the game will accept user input.

When I play games like The Binding of Isaac they accept user input on the main menu without me ever clicking them.

Is there a way to set the focus of my keyboard to my game without clicking it first? There was another question on this: [Have to click before pressing key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813613/have-to-click-before-pressing-key) , but it was left unanswered.

Comment: Java under which system? What's your main activity?

Comment: I'm super new so I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm compiling and running my program in eclipse? OSX. I'm using JFrames

Comment: Could you post the code of the view you're talking about?

Comment: https://twitter.com/RobersonWade/status/614160888422137856

Comment: You may want to call the Canvas constructor. Add super() to the first line of your constructor, also, try requesting focus after main.start, maybe something is "stealing" it right after, what's Main class, by the way?

Comment: IT WORKED! I left `frame.requestFocus();` before `main.start();` and then within `start()` I put `requestFocus();`. It doesn't seem to work without both. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I can't unless I know what's Main class and what does it do, but clearly something is calling requestFocus when being instantiated or manipulated within the start method. I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call window.requestFocus(); after calling main.start() so you override any other focus request done in the meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

If you have `JFrame`, or something like this (something inherited from `java.awt.Component`), you can try:

```
window.requestFocus();
```

[Link to javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus())

---

EDIT:
In case of `JFrame`, I have found this question:
[How to focus a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641172/how-to-focus-a-jframe)
One of the answer is the same as I advice
This can help you

Comment: @maskaconvnik This didn't seem to work for me. I tried to to use a few of the methods the answerers suggested none seemed to get the job done. Here's a screenshot of my current code: https://twitter.com/RobersonWade/status/614160888422137856